# User input to Project on JSON map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have the following D3.js project that is available here:

http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/raw/e75dcb649ae3b26e2312a63434fc970c/

The latitude and longitude inputs are below the map.

It's supposed to take user input numbers of latitude and longitude and "project" svg circles at the given coordinate. The issue is I'm either getting ____ is not a function error or dev tools throws no errors at all, but the circles are never projected.

It's a short file, can someone explain why it's not working the way I thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update function doesn't make any sense.

1. It accepts two inputs, but you only ever call it with one.
2. `.selectAll("circle").enter()` is not valid `d3` syntax.
3. You need to call `projection` with both the latitude and longitude, you pass `0` which will result in it returning `null` since it's outside of the projection.
4. After you fix all this, you'll still be off because you've moved your paths by your margin and would have been better off putting them in a `g` moved by the margins.

All that said, a simple rewrite would be:

```
var lat = d3.select("#latValue").on("input", function() {
    update();
}).node();

var long = d3.select("#lonValue").on("input", function() {
    update();
}).node();

function update() {

  // lat/long to pixel
  var coors = projection([long.value, lat.value]);

  // if outside projection don't add circle
  if (coors === null) return;

  // add circle
    container
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", coors[0])
        .attr("cy", coors[1])
        .attr("r", Math.sqrt(5) * 4)
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("opacity", 0.85);
}
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

/* On mouse hover, lighten state color */
path:hover {
 fill-opacity: .7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Width and height of map
var width = 960;
var height = 500;
var margins = { left: 0, top: 100, right: 0, bottom: 0 };
// D3 Projection
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
       .translate([width/2, height/2])    // translate to center of screen
       .scale([1000]);          // scale things down so see entire US

// Define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()               // path generator that will convert GeoJSON to SVG paths
      .projection(projection);  // tell path generator to use albersUsa projection

// Define linear scale for output
var color = d3.scale.linear()
     .range(["#c3e2ff","#15198e"]);

//Create SVG element and append map to the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height+margins.top);

svg.append('text')
  .text('Coordinate Query')
  .attr('font-size','24px')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 30 + ',' +70 + ')')
  .attr('font-family','Calibri');

svg.append('text')
  .text('Data as of 12/2016')
  .attr('font-size','12px')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 35 + ',' +100 + ')')
  .attr('font-family','Calibri');
// Load in my states data!
color.domain([0,100]); // setting the range of the input data
// Load GeoJSON data and merge with states data
d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/573228c3-d068-11e6-b16a-b501dc8d2b08", function(json) {

//var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
// Bind the data to the SVG and create one path per GeoJSON feature
var container = svg.append("g")
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');

container.selectAll("path")
 .data(json.features)
 .enter()
 .append("path")
 .attr("d", path)  
 .style("stroke", "#fff")
  .style("stroke-linejoin","round")
 .style("stroke-width", "1.5")
 .style("fill", 'steelblue');


// Modified Legend Code from Mike Bostock: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852
var lat = d3.select("#latValue").on("input", function() {
 update();
}).node();

var long = d3.select("#lonValue").on("input", function() {
 update();
}).node();

function update() {
  
  // lat/long to pixel
  var coors = projection([long.value, lat.value]);
  
  // if outside projection don't add circle
  if (coors === null) return;
  
  // add circle
 container
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", coors[0])
  .attr("cy", coors[1])
  .attr("r", Math.sqrt(5) * 4)
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("opacity", 0.85);

}
  
});
</script>
<p>
 <label  for="latValue"
     style="display: inline-block;width:240px;text-align:right;font-size:18px;font-family:Play">
     Lattitude:<span id="latValue-value"></span>
 </label>
 <input type="number"min="-360"max="360"step="1"value="0" id="latValue">
 <label  for="lonValue"
     style="display: inline-block;width:240px;text-align:right;font-size:18px;font-family:Play">
     Longitude:<span id="lonValue-value"></span>
 </label>
 <input type="number"min="-360"max="360"step="1"value="0" id="lonValue">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's stunning how badly I misunderstood this procedure. Thank you for helping me see my errors, the explanation made a lot of sense when I looked at the code again just now.

Comment: just out of curiosity, if I did want to call `.enter()` and later `.exit()` and `.remove()`, to prevent the circles from staying once the user updates the inputs, why can't I do that within the update function? When I add these calls in the function, it throws that error again.

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. I just need `.remove()`, nothing else.